# how i can connect the SQL Database from another server?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to connect my another website database and want to delete a table. but i'm really not doing that. below is my code:

```
<?php
$host = "http://website.com";
$username = "databaseUsername";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databaseName";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  // sql to delete a record
  $sql = "DELETE FROM wphe_links";

  // use exec() because no results are returned
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "Record deleted successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

while i'm trying to connect, the error log is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2059] Plugin http could not be loaded:
> /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

thanks.

Comment: Try the ip address instead of `http://website.com`

Comment: `$host` includes the protocol as well as the host name, it should be `$host = "website.com";`. This also assumes that the server will allow you to connect as it is commonly blocked from external access.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was tried with that method. not working.

Comment: IS the Username on the server setup to allow it to be used from a remote domain?

Comment: **Also WARNING** This query `$sql = "DELETE FROM wphe_links";` will delete the whole contents of the `wphe_links` table

Comment: @NigelRen while i'm trying [link]$host= "website.com"; it showing the error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'website.com' (115)

Comment: Also is the FireWall on the server setup to allow access via port 3306

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i want to delete the wpche_links whole contents from wpche_links table.

Comment: Your server need to allow remote connection, and the user used for connection need to be able to make remote connection too.

Comment: Open terminal on your server and `ping website.com` command. If you get the response means communication is established. If you get `connection time out` message means access is not allowed from your server.

Comment: @Inazo can you please post an answer for better understand?

Answer (score 0):

1. As RiggsFollys comment states, note that you cannot prefix host with protocol.
2. By default, you need to actively set the remote server to listen. It will only accept connections from localhost unless otherwise specified. Look into my.cnf file (or its equivalent on the specific system) and look for the bind_address (https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysql-network-security)
3. Grant the MySQL user external access (log in from the remote server and make sure the user can access from remote) :)

Apart from the mistake with http://, it is likely your remote server is not configured for remote connections :)